# Is there a name for the polynomial $x^n-a$?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, terminology

Let $A$ denote a ring. Then to each $a \in A$ and each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we get a polynomial $\mathrm{Poly}_x(a,n)$ defined as follows: $$\mathrm{Poly}_x(a,n) = x^n - a.$$ This defines a function $$\mathrm{Poly}_x:A \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A[x].$$

This family of polynomials seems to be quite fundamental, insofar as it arises whenever we adjoin abstract roots to a base ring to get a larger ring. For example, $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ can be defined as $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\mathrm{Poly}_x(2,2)$, and $\mathbb{C}$ can be defined as $\mathbb{R}[x]/\mathrm{Poly}_x(2,-1).$

Given how ubiquitous these polynomials are, it would be handy to have some terminology for them, like 'the degree $n$ polynomial for $a$.' This would be really handy in verbal discussions, for example if you're talking with someone about radical field extensions, etc.

> **Question.** Is there terminology for the polynomial $x^n-a$?

Comment: I hope not. We have already too many names for silly things.

Comment: Me making stuff up: "The $n^{th}$ roots of $a$ polynomial"

Comment: I'm not sure about the name of that polynomial specifically, but the extensions such as $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^n - a)$ are called Kummer Extensions